# SSIS: FileLoadException for System.Runtime Version 6.0.0.0 in .NET Framework Project

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage, .net-assembly

I'm facing a `FileLoadException` when running my Script component in SSIS 2022, specifically related to loading the `System.Runtime` assembly version 6.0.0.0. The complete error message is as follows:

`Could not load assembly l'assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`

In the SSIS package, I have Azure blob methods to upload some attachments.
All the Azure blob nugets are latest.

**Environment:**

- Target:  .NETframework 4.7
- Development environment: Visual Studio 2022
- Operating system: Windows 11

I found hundreds of suggestions, none helped me.

I added manually the assembly in app.config

`<dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/> </dependentAssembly>`, without result.

Comment: Don't know how you got there, but a v6 runtime I'm pretty sure is .NET Core.  I'd expect v4 for Framework

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's safe or not. Somewhere, somehow you tried to use a .NET Core library, possibly an Azure client library meant to run on .NET Core. SSIS doesn't work with .NET Core. .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. You can't use .NET Core libraries in a .NET Framework project.

Comment: @sadzag I don't believe you did.  .NET framework should have no knowledge of that runtime version.  Whatever you're doing to "recreate the whole project" is in fact reintroducing your problem.

Comment: Did you try using `Azure.Storage.Blobs`? While that package targets both .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Core, SQLCLR doesn't know about NuGet. When you deploy you'll have to ensure all the necessary binaries are included. That said, looking at the NuGet dependencies there doesn't seem to be something that points to System.Runtime 6.0 when you target .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Try using `WindowsAzure.Storage` and `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob`

Comment: Yes I am using Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.19.1. added from nuget

Comment: It seems working with Azure.Storage.Blob version 12.13.1, and have to register all the dlls(System.Text.Json, System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, ....) in the GAC

Comment: It is working now, but when I open the vstaProjects it claims the .netstandard2. I have to reinstall via nuget manager the blob nuget.; Painful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Steps:

- Downgraded Azure.Blob NuGet to version 12.13.1, ensuring compatibility solely with .NET Standard.
- Registered the necessary DLLs/NuGets in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

Troubleshooting Tips for SSIS or Console Applications:

- App.config Check: Ensure it references the correct version of NuGet packages, especially if multiple versions have been installed.
- NuGet Compatibility: Verify all installed NuGets for compatibility issues with the console application framework.